# Glide showing ImageView background in between loading images

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I've got a simple use case. I have a local image uri (`content://path`) that I load into an `ImageView` - that's step 1. After a button is pressed, the image is replaced with an image from our server - that's step 2.

My code is quite simple - or at least, I can reproduce the issue even after I simplified the code to the following:

```
Glide.with(imageHolder.getContext()).load(url).into(imageHolder);
```

The first time, this is called with a local uri (`content://path`), followed by a remote url (`http://path.com`).

Loading the local uri works just fine. The problem is that, once I initiate the load from the server (which might take a second), `Glide` rolls back to the `ImageView`'s background image colour. So visually I get old image -> background colour -> new image, which is quite annoying.

Is there some sort of a hidden way in Glide to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because while the server image is being loaded there is a gap between removing local image and showing the new one and that gap is your problem.
one of the workarounds to this issue is to give Glide a placeholder (set your local image as the placeholder) so while Glide is loading image from server it still shows the local image and once the server image is loaded the local one goes away.

```
Glide.with(imageHolder.getContext())
    .placeholder(YOUR_LOCAL_IMAGE_HERE)
    .load(url)
    .into(imageHolder);
```

Comment: Awesome workround. Ended up doing `.placeholder(imageHolder.getDrawable())`